# Deploying lightswitch desktop application error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I am having difficulty in deploying my forst lightswitch desktop application.
when i try to publish, in the summary window it says
Database: Donot Publish

and the install.htm file is cofusing to me.

Can someone help me with a step by step tutorial.
I will be grateful.

I have installed Microsoft SQL server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of deploying a LightSwitch-based application differs depending on the application type and deployment scenario that you select. You have said that your lightswitch application is a desktop application. So, the possible deployment scenarios are:

1. Desktop client 2-tier
2. Desktop client, 3-tier

These links will help you :

[Deploying LightSwitch Applications](http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff872288.aspx)

[How to: Deploy a 2-tier Application](http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff852056.aspx)

[How to: Deploy a 3-tier Application](http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg481778.aspx)

Comment: Thankyou for the quick reply. I was trying to follow the 2 tier tutorial. but when i test connection to the db it says error 40 - Couldnot open a connection to SQL server.

Comment: Hi thank you, now i can connect to the database, I deployed the application (2 tier). when i try to save to or retrieve from the data base it says: "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details." Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to get the exception info/stack trace from the server process (vslshost.exe) to get more information about the error when retrieving or saving data.  If your app tries to load data when opening, change it so that there is no default screen.  This will prevent the app from opening a screen when loading the app and trying to load data, allowing you enough time after opening the app to attach a debugger.  You can follow my blog post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mthalman/archive/2013/08/16/how-to-get-a-stack-trace-in-lightswitch.aspx for info on how to get the exception info.